# How to retrieve uploaded file edit view blade using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a project in Laravel-5.8 for upload of files like excel and images.

I have successfully inserted it. I saved the file name in the table and the file itself in a directly. Where I have a problem is how to retrieve the file in the edit view blade.

Controller

```
public function update_employee_mid_year_comment(UpdateSelfReviewRequest $request, $id) {
    $goal = Goal::find($id);  

    $goal->employee_mid_year_comment = $request->employee_mid_year_comment;

    if ($request->employee_mid_year_attachment != "") {
        $employee_mid_year_attachment = $request->file('employee_mid_year_attachment');
        $new_name = rand() . '.' . $employee_mid_year_attachment->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $employee_mid_year_attachment->move(public_path('storage/documents/mid_year'), $new_name);
        $goal->employee_mid_year_attachment = $new_name;
    }
    $goal->save();

    DB::commit();

    Session::flash('success', 'Comment is Successfully Updated');
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

I am using a modal form:

edit.blade

```
<div class="modal fade" id="edit{{ $goal->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <form action="{{route('mid_year_setups.update_employee_mid_year_comment',['id'=>$goal->id])}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit_comment-form">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="modal-header">
        Update Self-Review Comment
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Comment:<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
        <textarea rows="2" name="employee_mid_year_comment" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Comment here" value="{{old('employee_mid_year_comment',$goal->employee_mid_year_comment)}})}}" required data-validation-required-message="This field is required">{{old('employee_mid_year_comment',$goal->employee_mid_year_comment)}}</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label"> Attachment:</label>
        <div class="custom-file">
            <div class="custom-file">
            <input value="{{old('employee_mid_year_attachment',$goal->employee_mid_year_attachment)}}" type="file" name="employee_mid_year_attachment" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile">Choose file</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" id="edit_comment_btn-submit" class="btn btn-success btn-ok">Save</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The file name is employee_mid_year_attachment while the file path is: storage/documents/mid_year

When I rendered the edit view blade, it didn't retrieve the attached document.  How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting to actually edit the file, or just the values of the database row?

Comment: @Ballard - I want to display the file nameand it's extension. I don't have problem with edit text input and others. Like the text input there got displayed.. But it didn't display anything for the attachment

Answer (score 0):

use in value input path to file

```
 <input 
 value="{{asset('storage/documents/mid_year/'.$goal>employee_mid_year_attachment')}}" 
  type="file" name="employee_mid_year_attachment" class="custom-file-input" 
  id="customFile">
```

Comment: I now have   <input value="{{asset('storage/documents/mid_year/'.$goal>employee_mid_year_attachment')}}"  type="file" name="employee_mid_year_attachment" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">       But I got this error:  syntax error, unexpected '')); ?>" value="<?php echo e(o'

Comment: You don't need to get the old file. If you do not change it in the DB and storage when doing the update, it will still there, or will be still null if it was.

You can prepare the array with the data to update from the beginning of the method and add the image element, only if it is present.

Comment: and in your controller  if($request->hasFile('employee_mid_year_attachment')){ update file}

Comment: and if you need to retrieve  old file you can show it in img tag         <img src="{{asset('storage/documents/mid_year/'.$goal>employee_mid_year_attachment')}}">

Comment: The file is not just image. It could be pdf, excel